# .NET Reflection, Expecting System.String getting System.Object instead

Tags: .net, reflection

I am hoping someone can point me in the correct direction. I have a method (A) that returns the result of another method that is invoked via reflection (B). A returns a type of Object, however the method invoked with (B) returns a string.

When I run my application locally, and do:

```
    object x = A(); 
    string y = x.GetType().ToString();
```

The value of 'y' is System.String as expected. When I run this exact same code in production (and yes, it is the exact same code/libraries/executable/etc. I have no hair left to prove it :) ), 'y' is System.Object. This ends up causing an error downstream.

Can anyone give me an idea of what is causing this difference? Locally I am running a physical copy of Windows 7 Professional. In production, I am running a virtualized Windows Server 2008 Standard. This application is written in .NET 3.5. Methods A and B are written a VB.NET library. The calling application is written in C#.

Comment: With same executable you mean no different debug/release build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I have resolved the issue. As it turns out, the System.Object coming back the production environment was accurate. The method called by A, uses a ByRef Object variable, the variable gets set to a string and is returned.

When that variable was getting set in production, an exception was being thrown and getting swallowed. When the method finished executing, the ByRef was never assigned the string value and hence was still a System.Object.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not to be obvious, but it must not be the same code. If it were the same code, it would most likely have the same result.

Are you working with the source of the VB.NET library? If you do, since you have the source it's calling the source of the method, so it can deduce the type automatically, whereas with the 'production' version, it can't deduce the type because it's calling from an assembly or something.

There is an easy fix:

```
object x = A();
object xCasted = x as string;
if(x == null) ; //you have issues
```

Comment: Hi Shlomo, thanks for the response. I have tried the casting solution as you have suggested, however all I end up with is an InvalidCastException (Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.String'.)